# Unable to dismiss DialogFragment in retained instance fragment after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a progress dialog (implemented using `DialogFragment`) re-inside a retained instance fragment.

If there's no configuration change, the `DialogFragment` can be dismissed without any issues.

However, if there's configuration change, calling `dismiss` would not have any effect.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            BackupTaskFragment backupTaskFragment = BackupTaskFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("BACKUP_TASK_FRAGMENT");
            if (oldFragment != null) {
                fm.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
            }

            fm.beginTransaction().add(backupTaskFragment, "BACKUP_TASK_FRAGMENT").commit();
        }
    }
}
```

### BackupTaskFragment.java

```
public class BackupTaskFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final class BackupTaskDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public static BackupTaskDialogFragment newInstance() {
            return new BackupTaskDialogFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Backup...");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            return progressDialog;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this instance so it isn't destroyed when MainActivity and
        // MainFragment change configuration.
        setRetainInstance(true);

        backupTask = new BackupTask(this);

        backupTask.execute();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isResumed() && backupTask != null) {
                    backupTaskDialogFragment = BackupTaskDialogFragment.newInstance();

                    FragmentManager fm = BackupTaskFragment.this.getFragmentManager();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(backupTaskDialogFragment, BACKUP_TASK_DIALOG_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            }
        }, 1500);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onPause");

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();

        boolean kill = false;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (activity != null && false == activity.isChangingConfigurations()) {
                // Stop the thread when home is pressed.
                kill = true;
            }
        } else {
            // I have no idea how to perform configuration checking in older API
            // Just do nothing, by letting the thread continue to run.
            //
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458540/calling-activity-ischangingconfigurations-in-fragment-for-api-level-lesser-than
        }

        if (kill) {
            if (backupTask != null) {
                backupTask.cancel(true);
                backupTask = null;
            }

            BackupTaskDialogFragment backupTaskDialogFragment = this.backupTaskDialogFragment;
            if (backupTaskDialogFragment != null) {
                android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onPause dismiss backupTaskDialogFragment");
                backupTaskDialogFragment.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
    // This is also called by the AsyncTask.
    public void onPostExecute(File file) {
        if (isResumed()) {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onPostExecute isResumed true");
        } else {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onPostExecute isResumed false");
        }

        backupTask = null;

        BackupTaskDialogFragment backupTaskDialogFragment = this.backupTaskDialogFragment;
        if (backupTaskDialogFragment != null) {
            android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "onPostExecute dismiss backupTaskDialogFragment");
            backupTaskDialogFragment.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public static BackupTaskFragment newInstance() {
        return new BackupTaskFragment();
    }

    private BackupTask backupTask;

    private BackupTaskDialogFragment backupTaskDialogFragment = null;

    private static final String BACKUP_TASK_DIALOG_FRAGMENT = "BACKUP_TASK_DIALOG_FRAGMENT";
}
```

### BackupTask.java

```
public class BackupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {

    public BackupTask(BackupTaskFragment backupTaskFragment) {
        this.backupTaskFragment = backupTaskFragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "BackupTask sleep for 20 seconds...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "BackupTask sleep for 20 seconds done!");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
        this.backupTaskFragment.onPostExecute(file);
    }

    private final BackupTaskFragment backupTaskFragment;
}
```

As you can see, when `BackupTask` finishes execution, it will trigger `BackupTaskFragment`'s onPostExecute, to dismiss `BackupTaskDialogFragment`.

However, is there's configuration change before `BackupTaskFragment`'s onPostExecute, dismissing `BackupTaskDialogFragment` doesn't work.

Any idea why it doesn't work, and how can we resolve this?

The complete minimal workable code can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcy856zmp18dhgk/MyApplication.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of trying to manage fragment transactions through config changes. It's a pain, trust me. Your best bet is likely to remove the DialogFragment in `onPause()` and then to re-create it in `onCreate()` if it needs to be. That's the only way I've been able to get retained Fragments to persist across config chagnes...by just setting and storing a bunch of "state" variables.

Comment: The way you handle the creation and display of the DialogFragment doesn't seem right. Why do you use a `FragmentTransaction`? There's an other method you should use [DialogFragment#show(Context context, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show). And in order to dismiss the `DialogFragment` you simply get it via the FragmentManager and dismiss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's configuration change, `this.backupTaskDialogFragment` in `BackupTaskFragment` no longer refer to current running dialog fragment.

Instead of

```
BackupTaskDialogFragment backupTaskDialogFragment = this.backupTaskDialogFragment;
if (backupTaskDialogFragment != null) {
```

Use

```
public BackupTaskDialogFragment getBackupTaskDialogFragment() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
        return (BackupTaskDialogFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(BACKUP_TASK_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    }
    return null;
}
...
BackupTaskDialogFragment backupTaskDialogFragment = getBackupTaskDialogFragment();
if (backupTaskDialogFragment != null) {
```